# sending data from my android app to my computer via internet

Tags: android

is it possible to let my android app send data(or better, files) to my computer (windows 10) via internet(e.g. both being connecting to a wifi, but not necessarily the same)?

Comment: The main problem will be to set up the networking. Normally, a machine connected to some wifi will not be reachable from outside without some special configuration of the router.

Answer (score 1):

In your cases if not in the same network then the phone needs to send the data to a server database then you computer my get the data from that server.
 You may user a locally hosted server wamp or host it on one of the many free/paid for hosting services available

For simple data sync you may use php & mysql on the server side and  json from the app.